# HTTP response check and record the downtime of a website in Python

Tags: python, ping

I am trying to build an application where I will ping a website in every 5 seconds and it will record the downtime of that website. If the response is anything else than 200 status code then it will record the time and it will also keep a record when it is back to 200 status code. I am writing the script in Python and ready to use any database. What is the recommended way to store the data in database i.e time of downtime and time when it's recovered.

I don't want to write every single response for every check in the database. It will write into the database only when response is anything else than 200 and also write the time when it is back to 200.

```
host = "google.com"
port = "80"

def porthit(host, port):
    try:
        r = requests.get('http://'+host+':'+port, timeout=5)
        if r.status_code == 200:    
            print(r.status_code)
            status_msg = "running"
            return status_msg    
    except Exception, e:
        print ("no connection")
        status_msg = "disconnect"
        return status_msg
```

Suppose, at 16:38 website is giving 500 status code and it gives 200 OK status code at 16:40 then in the database only this two values will be recorded.

I can also create a DB connection, but not sure how store this specific two entries,

```
conn = psycopg2.connect("host='localhost' port='5432' dbname='pingtest' user='admin' password='admin'")
```

Comment: Ping the website. Look at the most recent entry in your database. If the code has changed, record the current time and the current code. If there is no change, do nothing.

Comment: could you explain what have you imported too?

Answer (score 1):

> What is the recommended way to store the data in database i.e time of downtime and time when it's recovered.

I guess the best option would be is to store time as the [unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)

Also from implementing perspective, one of the naive implementations is listed below, basically you might won't to define `while True` loop with the time.sleep call ( for a 5 seconds):

```
import time
import requests


def get_status(host, port):
    try:
        r = requests.get('http://'+host+':'+port, timeout=5)
        if r.status_code == 200:
            status_msg = "running"
            status = True
        else:
            status = False
            status_msg = r.text
    except Exception as exc:
        status = False
        status_msg = exc.message
    return status, status_msg

def start_check(host, port):
    while True:
        is_service_available, error_message = get_status(host, port)
        if not is_service_available:
            # Database update logic.
        time.sleep(5)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Host and port may be passed as args to the script.
    host, port = 'google.com', '80'
    start_check(host, port)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your program needs to detect and print/store changes, so you're really interested in comparing the current state to the previous state. So:

Imports:

```
from datetime import datetime
import time
import requests
```

Function to ping the server:

```
def porthit (host, port):    
    last_status = 0
    last_err = ''

    while True:
        try:
            resp = requests.get(host + ':' + port, timeout = 5)
            # has the status changed? 
            if resp.status_code != last_status:
                # parse the date and time from the response -- e.g. for Google these are
                # 'Date': 'Tue, 07 Aug 2018 13:45:09 GMT'
                resp_time = datetime.strptime( resp.headers['Date'], "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z")
                # print out a message with the time and new server code
                print(resp_time.isoformat() + ': server code ' + str(resp.status_code))

                # write time, status in DB
                store_results( resp_time.isoformat(), resp.status_code )

                # set the new status
                last_status = resp.status_code
                # reset the last error message
                last_err = ''

        except Exception as e:
            # is this the same as our last error message?
            if str(e) != last_err:
                print (datetime.now().isoformat() + ': ' + str(e) )
                last_err = str(e)
                # set status to zero so that a message will be printed when the connection is back up
                last_status = 0


        time.sleep(5)
```

You may want to do some nicer error handling; the [requests documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/) has more information on the exceptions that are raised so you can handle them appropriately. You might also want to reduce the ping frequency depending on what error you're getting.

You can store your results however you like once you've figured out what backend you're going to use:

```
def store_results (time, code):
# implement this however you want
```

and call `porthit(servername, port)` to kick it all off.

Sample console output (pinging a server on my localhost):

```
2018-08-07T15:55:46.113097: No connection adapters were found for 'httpz://www.example.dev:80/'
2018-08-07T14:55:48: server code 200
2018-08-07T15:55:58.502277: server code 404
2018-08-07T15:56:21.509191: server code 200
```